# Non-linear black box System identification

Tags: matlab

I am trying to do a non linear black box model identification based on a dataset an input, output

I tried using an ARX polynomial type method, but nothing come out of it.

Then I tried soemthing similar to this: [non-linear grey box System identification with Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686921/non-linear-grey-box-system-identification-with-matlab)

Any other idea?

Comment: Removed tags from title; grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the identification data something like this:

> d_id_w=iddata(w_id,u_id,dt)

And the validation data :

> d_vd_w=iddata(w_vd,u_vd,dt)

The ARX model: 
First, you create it:

> m_w_arx=arx(d_id_w,[1,1,1]);

Then you validate the model:

> resid(m_w_arx,d_vd_w)

You also may do a comparison between the output of the model and its measured output:

> compare(d_vd_w,m_w_arx)